# Optimize multidimensional array creation

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have a list of array keys and nesting level in one array, for example:

```
$keys[0] = 'first';
$keys[1] = 'second';
$keys[2] = 'third';
```

How can I transform this into a multidimensional array in the following format:

```
$array['first']['second']['third'] = 'value';
```

I tried a couple different variations that did not work out and the keys overwrote themselves. The simplest way is to get a count of the number of keys and manually cover each scenario but this is hardly optimized and does not dynamically grow.

```
$keyLen = count($keys);

if ($keyLen == 1) {
    $array[$keys[0]] = 'value;
} elseif ($keyLen == 2) {
    $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]] = 'value;
} elseif ($keyLen == 3) {
    $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]] = 'value';
} ...
```

A couple notes, the value is not of significance it's the nesting of the array keys, and I cannot change the initial array format.

Comment: What are the values? Is it a static string `'value'`?

Comment: Where do you have the `value`? It's the last item in your array?

Comment: I'd suggest a recoursive function - but from last item (key2) to first item (key0). Or maybe just a loop start from last item will do.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: @Dharman I stated at the bottom of the question that the value does not matter. I am able to populate that part, it's the arrangement of the keys that I can't optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go backwards through your input array and wrap the previous result as you go:

```
$nested = 'value';
for (end($keys); key($keys)!==null; prev($keys)){
    $nested = [current($keys) => $nested];
}
```

At the end `$nested` will have the desired structure.

Comment: A couple of these answer my question but you were first. That'll do!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Here we're using references to stack our new arrays.

```
<?php
$keys = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$array = array();
$current = &$array;
foreach($keys as $key => $value) {
    $current[$value] = array();
    $current = &$current[$value];
}
$current = 'Hello world!';
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the last Item you can loop through the array, pop the last one and build the new array:

```
<?php
$keys[0] = 'first';
$keys[1] = 'second';
$keys[2] = 'third';

function createKey($array) {
    $b = "value";
    while(count($array)>0) {
      $key = array_pop($array);
      $b = [$key => $b];
    }
    return $b;
}

var_dump(createKey($keys));
// Output:
array(1) {
  ["first"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["second"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["third"]=>
      string(5) "value"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to loop the reversed keys and wrap the previous result:

```
$array = [];
foreach(array_reverse($keys) as $key) {
    $temp = $array;
    unset($array[key($array)]);
    $array[$key] = $temp;
}
```

Then you could set your value:

```
$array['first']['second']['third'] = 'value';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XPaaG)

Answer (score 0):

You could even `eval` this in a safe way without leaking any input data into the eval-string:

```
$value = 'value';
eval( '$array[$keys['. implode(']][$keys[', range(0, count($keys)-1)) . ']] = $value;' );
```

or with an additional counter even simpler and shorter:

```
$value = 'value';
$i     = 0;
eval( '$array' . str_repeat('[$keys[$i++]]', count($keys)) . ' = $value;' );
```